Gmail new Message shows as a popup page
From few days back, when I try to compose a new email in Gmail it shows as a popup page instead of docking into the right.
This is very annoying. So far my search have failed to find a fix. I could not find a section in setting to fix this.

"This is very annoying" It would be helpful if you edited your question to explain "why" it is annoying.  Presumably, it interferes in some way with your workflow, and perhaps that information would help provide a solution.  Also,  "docking into the right" needs to be clarified. perhaps include a screenshot or mockup of your desired behavior.

I have edited my answer to include a new tab/new window option.  Does that address your needs?

Below are two approaches to change the window behavior when editing messages:

Pop-out messages in a new tab or window
Default new messages to full screen (not popped-out)

Pop-Out Messages in a New Tab or Window

New Message:
While clicking  hold down Ctrl to open in a new tab or Ctrl for a window.
From an Open Message:
While clicking Full Screen hold down Ctrl to open in a new tab or Shift for a window.

Restore from Tab or Window
To restore the default (docked/popped-in) position of a message, click the pop-in button


Default New Messages to "Full Screen" (Not Popped-Out)

Compose a new message.
Click on the "More options" button on the bottom right of the menu bar

Uncheck "Default to full screen"

Future new messages will no longer open in full-screen mode.



This does not answer my question. Yes new email will not show as a full screen but it is still a popup window which does not dock.  This appear to be stupid new behavior from Google. email.  I'm seeing posts from lots of unhappy users.

Your question is unclear. It would be helpful if you edited it to include a screenshot of what you are experiencing and ideally one of what you want to experience (or if impossible a mockup or better description)
